# Convert plain text to deeply json object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, filter

I have one plain string including some conditions like this.

`const optionString = '{2109} AND ({2370} OR {1701} OR {2702}) AND {1234} AND ({2245} OR {2339})';`

I need to get object like the following structure from above.

```
const output = {
  and: [
    2109,
    { or: [2370, 1071, 2702] },
    1234,
    { or: [2245, 2339] },
  ];
```

Currently, I have tried to do like following

```
function parseFormat(strArg) {
  var
    category,
    output = [],  // Output
    str = strArg.trim();  // Remove unwanted space before processing

  str.split('AND').forEach(function(line) {
    var removedString = line.replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, '');
    var item = removedString.split('OR');
     
    item = item.map(it => {
      return Number(it.replace(/ /g, ''))
    })
    if(item.length > 0) {
        output.push(item)
    } else {
        output.push(item[0])
    }
  
    });
  return output;
}
```

And its output is like here.

```
[
    [
        1069
    ],
    [
        1070,
        1071,
        1072
    ],
    [
        1244
    ],
    [
        1245,
        1339
    ]
]
```

I have one question first

- How to add key AND and OR in the current result?

If you know a good solution on the performance side, please update me.
Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: What logic are you using to end up with that output? Have you made any attempt(s) yourself, when you tried - and you do need to make a credible effort, even in pseudo-code to show you've thought through the problem - what went wrong? In what way? Please, read both "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" for guidance on how to improve your question.

Comment: Regular expressions and recursion might help. It gets complicated to write and test. Let me know what you try.

Comment: @iohans  

Thanks for your reply.
I updated my post with my current result.

Comment: @DavidThomas
Same as for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const optionString = '{2109} AND ({2370} OR {1701} OR {2702}) AND {1234} AND ({2245} OR {2339})';

const parseExpr = s => {
  let op, m, a = [];
  while(s?.length) {
    if(m = /^{(?<num>[0-9]+)}( (?<rest>.*))?/.exec(s)) {
      a.push(+m.groups.num);
      s = m.groups.rest;
    }
    else if(m = /^(?<op>[A-Z]+)( (?<rest>.*))?/.exec(s)) {
      let t = m.groups.op.toLowerCase();
      if(op && op!==t) throw new Error('Multiple operators cannot exist at same level in syntax tree')
      else op = t;
      s = m.groups.rest;
    }
    else if(s.startsWith('(')) {
      for(let i=0, level=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i)==='(') level++;
        if(s.charAt(i)===')') level--;
        if(!level) {
          a.push(parseExpr(s.substring(1, i)));
          s = s.substring(i+2);
          break;
        }
        if(i===s.length-1) throw new Error('Mismatched brackets')
      }
    }
    else throw new Error(`Unparseable expression: ${s}`);
  }
  return { [op]: a };
}

const result = parseExpr(optionString)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your good sample.
Btw, can we update this to approve including several AND conditions in the sub-group?

```const optionString = '{1069} AND ({1070} AND ({1071} OR {1071} OR {1072}) AND {1244} AND ({1245} OR {1339})'```

Comment: @hakuna the string you just pasted is missing a `)`. I've updated the code to throw an error in that circumstance

Comment: Great.
Thanks for your kindly supporting.